# Are computed columns in a view persisted?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

```
CREATE VIEW [dbo].[MyView] ([ID],[VisitDate],[StartDate] ,[EndDate])
WITH SCHEMABINDING  

    AS
    SELECT     id, VisitDate,dateadd(dd,-10,VisitDate)persisted,
       dateadd(dd,10,VisitDate)persisted
    FROM         dbo.Visits
```

I have a non-clustered index on ID and VisitDate.I wantd to know if the computed columns StartDate and Enddate is persisted or is it calculated runtime when view is referenced

EDIT:**what if i have a unique clustered index on ID and VisitDate.In that case will these columns become persisted?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your view, the values are calculated at runtime. The word "persisted" there is treated as the column name, not a special keyword.

If you want to create calculated columns that are persisted, you need to do so as part of the table definition, either in the CREATE TABLE statement, or as an UPDATE TABLE statement. You could also consider using an indexed view.

See the documentation for more details:

- [Computed Columns](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191250.aspx)
- [Creating Indexed Views](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191432.aspx)

Comment: How can there be two columns named persisted?

Comment: @HemalPandya: that's **not** the column's **name** - it's just an attribute on the column! You can have any number of computed columns (with separate names) which are persisted

Comment: @Hemal - That would normally raise an error as column names must be unique in Views but in this case the OP gives the columns explicit names at the beginning of the View definition `[ID],[VisitDate],[StartDate] ,[EndDate]` so this is ignored.

Comment: I am confused. My question was prompted by the answer that ""persisted" there is treated as the column name".

Comment: @Hermal - It **is** treated as the column name. Without the column list at the beginning of the view the OP would get the error `Column names in each view or function must be unique. Column name 'persisted' in view or function 'MyView' is specified more than once.` but their use of an explicit column alias list overrides the inline column aliases.

Comment: @Martin What if i have an indexed view?

Comment: @AshleyJohn - If you have an indexed view all columns will be persisted automatically without any need to mark them as persisted.

Comment: @MartinSmith: You should put your last comment as an answer.

Answer (score 2):

Yes.

> The result set of an **indexed view** is physically persisted in the
>   database in a manner similar to that of typical table storage.

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd171921(v=sql.100).aspx

Comment: Good answer. It does also say "**After a unique clustered index is created on the view**, the view's result set is materialized immediately and persisted in physical storage in the database, saving the overhead of performing this costly operation at execution time.". Of course an index is required to hack microsoft's materialised views into a working state (in typical ms [@rs3-about-face](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/arse_about_face) fasion), and thus are then also coincidentally indexed views.